# Cropping face Using OPENCV python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, crop, face-recognition

I am using *opencv* for face detection, and in addition I want to crop the faces and save them,

How can I do it?

The form of the face array: for *(x, y, w, h)* in faces

Comment: `cropped = img[ y : y+h, x : x+w ]`

Comment: @berak Thank you! how can i save this as a png file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
id = 1    
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cropped = img[ y : y+h, x : x+w ]
    cv2.imwrite("cropped_face" + str(id) + ".png", cropped)
    id++
```

Comment: Hey @Tom ! Thanks its working, but its saves only one pic, how can i save more then one  ? (In case i have more then 1 face ?)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
 cropped = image[ y : y+h, x : x+w ]
 cv2.imwrite("cropped_face.png", cropped)

Comment: I updated the solution. If it works, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.